Ubuntu 24.04 hdmi functions, but ' restarts' randomly while in use
I play guitar alongside music from youtube throug my stereo, and experiencing a problem which is unbearable for that....
The HDMI output of my laptop connects to my stereo through HDMI and my stereo is connected to my tv through another HDMI. I can use my tv as a second monitor. But for music I can just connect to the stereo without the monitor
I recently replaced windows10 for Ubuntu 24.04. And I upgraded my RAM from 6GB to 16GB. Ubuntu 24.04 was installed on a brand new SSD hard disk.
Under Windows there were no issues nor lagging.
Under Ubuntu however, the HDMI functions (=connects) for sound and/or video, as a '2nd' screen or as the main screen.
The problem is that while playing music from Youtube (while the player is on my laptop screen), it seems the sound stops for 1-2 seconds and then continues, and it happens every couple of minutes (without a fixed interval), so initially I thought it was a memory or processor problem.
While running 'system monitor' during playing youtube music there were no peaks (max values) to be seen.
I did notice that everytime the sound 'cuts' the display of my receiver also 'refreshed', which also happens when you initially connect a HDMI device. But what's even stranger, is that while watching video, the video itself, or the imagery if you will (even while on the tv/2nd screen) is not pausing nor lagging, but only the sound is 'interrupted'....
I then tried different HDMI ports on my receiver and switched to different HDMI cables, but the problem keeps repeating itself.
So my best guess now is that there is something with my 'soundcard' if there is even such a thing present in my laptop..... (which is a HP pavilion 17" Beatsaudio)
Any ideas what to do about it (I'm a complete novice on Ubuntu, so please advice with complete command lines if possible.) I'm also glad to give any additional info when needed (for insight in my system and/or settings, just tell me which command to run for that....
Thanks!

This will be problematic to debug without some details of your complete setup. However, take a look at the answer from the following link https://superuser.com/questions/1558361/how-to-fix-crackling-stuttering-sound-in-linux-ubuntu-debian-guest-and-win

thank you for the link, but that didn't work....
Any command line I can type to provide you with info on my system?
